# Can't edit the Default applications

Tags: applications

I have a Samsung galaxy 3,  the Touchwhiz Home is greyed out in the Default applications, nothing else comes up can't pick a default.

How do I edit the default applications in order to select Touch Wiz home?

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting app preferences

Go to Settings > Apps > Tap on the three dot menu > Select *Reset app preferences*

This option resets default apps etc and check again and see if you can select Touch Wiz home.

Also check in *Configure apps* menu

On home app choose *Touch Wiz*